# Why is my code printing a blank file?

Tags: java, string, class, object, int

I was working on a project for my AP Computer Science class that allows the user to sort music, when I came across a bug. The program parses a line in this format -> `year (tab) rank (tab) artist (tab) title (tab)`. It then can sort or filter the songs by year, rank, artist and/or title. This information is loaded through an input file that is formatted like:

```
2008    50  Ashley Tisdale  He Said, She Said
2008    123 Taylor Swift    Teardrops On My Guitar
2008    233 Finger Eleven   Paralyzer
2008    258 Paramore    Misery Business
...
```

This is what I have tried.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GazillionSongs {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      System.out.println("Hello and welcome to my AP Computer Science Music Sorting Project!"); 
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the input file: ");
      String in = kb.nextLine();
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(in));

      System.out.print("Enter sort/filter command: ");
      String command = kb.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter an output file: ");
      String out = kb.nextLine();

      File f = new File(out);

      if (f.exists()) {
         System.out.println("Error: output file already exists...");
      } else {
         PrintStream outFile = new PrintStream(new File(out));

         ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

         while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            lines.add(line);  
         }

         ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

         Scanner allCommands = new Scanner(command);

         for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            int year = 0;
            int rank = 0;
            String artist = "";
            String title = "";
            Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
            song.parse(lines.get(i));
            songs.add(song);
         }

         SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection(songs);

         while (allCommands.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
               String command2 = allCommands.next();
               String[] tokens = command2.split(":");
               if (tokens[0].equals("year")) {
                  int min = 0;
                  int max = 0;
                  Range range = new Range(min, max);
                  range.parse(tokens[1]);
                  songCollection.filterYear(range);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("rank")) {
                  int min = 0;
                  int max = 0;
                  Range range = new Range(min, max);
                  range.parse(tokens[1]);
                  songCollection.filterRank(range);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("artist")) {
                  songCollection.filterArtist(tokens[1]);
               }
               if (tokens[0].equals("title")) {
                  songCollection.filterTitle(tokens[1]);
               }
            }
         }
         outFile.print(songCollection.toString());         
      }
   }                  
}
```

and

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Song {
       private static int year;
       private static int rank;
       private static String artist;
       private static String title;

       public Song(int year, int rank, String artist, String title) {
          this.year = year;
          this.rank = rank;
          this.artist = artist;
          this.title = title;
       }

       public static Song parse(String s) {
          String[] tokens = s.split("\t");
          year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
          rank = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
          artist = tokens[2];
          title = tokens[3];
          Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
          return song;
       }

       public int getYear() {
          return this.year;
       }

       public int getRank() {
          return this.rank;
       }

       public String getArtist() {
          return this.artist;
       }

       public String getTitle() {
          return this.title;
       }

       public String toString() {
          String convertString = year + "/t" + rank + "/t" + artist + "/t" + title;
          return convertString;
       }     
    }
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class Range {
   private int min;
   private int max;

   public int getMin() { 
      return min; 
   }
   public int getMax() { 
      return max; 
   }

   public Range(int  min, int max) {
      this.min = min;
      this.max = max;
   }

   public static Range parse(String s) {
      String[] range = s.split("-");
      int min = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
      int max = 1;

      try {
         max = Integer.parseInt(range[1]);
      } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException err10) {
         max = Integer.parseInt(range[0]);
      }  

      if(min > max){
         return new Range(max,min);   
      } else {
         return new Range(min,max);
      }
   }

   public boolean contains(int n) {
      if(n <= max && n >= min) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class SongCollection {

   private ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();

   public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
      this.songs = songs;
   }

   public ArrayList<Song> getList() {
      return songs;
   }

   public void filterYear(Range r) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!r.contains(songs.get(i).getYear())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterRank(Range r) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!r.contains(songs.get(i).getRank())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterArtist(String s) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!songs.get(i).getArtist().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void filterTitle(String s) {
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         if(!songs.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
            songs.remove(i);
            i--;
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortYear() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getYear() < songs.get(j).getYear(); j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortRank() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getRank() < songs.get(j).getRank(); j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortTitle() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getTitle().toLowerCase().compareTo(songs.get(j).getTitle().toLowerCase()) < 0; j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public void sortArtist() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= songs.size(); i++) {
         Song temp = songs.get(i);
         int j;
         for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && temp.getArtist().toLowerCase().compareTo(songs.get(j).getArtist().toLowerCase()) < 0; j--) {
            songs.set((j + 1), songs.get(j));
            songs.set((j), temp);
         }
      }
   }

   public String toString() {
      String stringOfSong = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < songs.size(); i++) {
         stringOfSong += songs.get(i).toString() + "\n";
      }
      return stringOfSong;
   }
}
```

Why is the file blank when I output the information? I would really appreciate the help, as I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now?

Comment: Seriously, you just posted this same question verbatim last night, get a JavaScript debugger.

Comment: it's just java, and yeah ik, but no one had the correct response. @ColeChamberlain

Comment: You are never closing `outFile`, and you were told that in the previous posting. Do not double-post here. Period.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been posted and answered.

Comment: @EJP that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have a few major errors here, which I would not personally expect to find in the code of an APCS class.

- In the *Song* class, you've got a major no-no happenening: all of your fields that should be instance fields, are in fact static. Secondly, your *Song.parse(String s)* method, is returning on a (albeit messed up) singleton basis. It would be better to remove all of the static modifiers, and to simply have the parse method return itself (*this*).
- Song has no default constructor, and you struggle with this a little in the for loop starting at *GazillionSongs*.38.
- All of your filter methods in the SongCollection class are broken, i.e. they do not work, because you are removing a item from a list that you are traversing.  This is important though!  Because you aren't getting any errors from this (since you didn't say so), one can see that they are never being called successfully.  This of course further shows that you didn't test your code in unit-test format, or even just simply going through and running it.  It is at this point that I have stopped trying to assess your code, and can only provide you with the following advice: check everything you wrote first, before asking for help.  Even then, ask your teacher, as they can explain it to you in person, and will most likely receive less of a headache from it.

If you still really want me to, let me just say that the reason you are getting a blank document, other than the utter lack of correctness in a lot of these things (not that that is bad; you are a student after all, and these ways of coding can be fixed), is that in line *GazillionSongs*.50, where you start a while loop, something goes wrong; in that, said while loop never runs, and an empty ArrayList *songs* is printed.

I hope this helped, and shed a bit of light unto you. Best of luck, and dare I say, you might need it. All my apologies in hind-sight.

```
// Edit: the comments are absolutely correct. Closing the file tends to help, but I felt it was 
// self-explanatory amongst the many other errors.
```

Comment: He posted the same question last night and deleted the post.